# Chrome adds <br> to contenteditable span with a :after if its content is deleted; bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, contenteditable

Is the following functionality a bug in Chrome, or is it correct behavior that I don't understand?

In Chrome (version 25), if I have a content editable span which has a node added after it through a :after css class, as in this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yQBvn/

if I delete all of the content of the span, after I've deleted the last character, Chrome adds a `<br>` to the content editable span.  This doesn't feel right.

I've verified that Chrome does not do this if the :after css content isn't added, and I've verified that Firefox doesn't do this in any case.

Comment: I'm finding that Chrome 25 is still adding the <br> even with the css removed.

Comment: I don't see that.  Here's the same example without the css (with a second span to make it clear if a <br> is added) http://jsfiddle.net/y3mDa/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wanna see something CRAZY?!

http://jsfiddle.net/joeframbach/VXMEN/

```
<body>
<div id="EDIT-AREA">
    <span class='CHARACTER-NAME' contenteditable='true'>Bob</span><span>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
</body>
```

Adding a span with a space after it fixes the problem. Don't ask me why or how.

Comment: Thanks!  That's really all I needed. I'll accept in a few minutes if no one offers a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: Probably a bug in chrome. Feel free to submit a ticket through chrome's official channels, whatever those may be.

Comment: This is kind of interesting. I looked through the bugtracker and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Last night I submitted a bug report through the integrated chrome bug system -- though maybe I should have just gone to the chromium site and done it directly there instead of through google.

Comment: This response made my morning.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox also does this using a DIV with contenteditable

Delete ALL content in the content editable and bam  br  tag.

Start with an empty CE, focus & hit space, bam  br

Solution above of using an empty element directly after a div does nothing, with or without a pseudo element like :after.

Span works though?

Chrome untested.